# Export each client's orders to separate CSV file

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, export-to-csv

I have the below query:

```
Select CustomerID, OrderName, OrderQuantity 
from Customers C join Orders O on C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
```

Result:

```
CutomerID | OrderName | OrderQuantity
1001      | Chicken   | 2
1001      | Meat      | 5
1002      | Pepsi     | 13
1002      | 7Up       | 7
```

Is there anyway to export each customer rows to separate CSV files?

---

so `customer1001.csv` file will have

```
CutomerID | OrderName | OrderQuantity
1001      | Chicken   | 2
1001      | Meat      | 5
```

and `customer1002.csv` file will have

```
CutomerID | OrderName | OrderQuantity
1002      | Pepsi     | 13
1002      | 7Up       | 7
```

Comment: How are you exporting to CSV now? You could do this in SSIS

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I didn't write any code yet - and I can use SSIS, but how you will accomplish this via SSIS?

Comment: To do it in SSIS, you generate a recordset with `SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID FROM YourTable`, then you use that to drive a for each loop. Then inside the loop you generate a filename and select data for just that customer ID. Here is the concept: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/implementing-foreach-looping-logic-in-ssis/

Comment: If you don't want to use SSIS, @sarslan has a great answer below

Comment: I am trying @sarslan answer - seems to be quite good answer I agree.
Just getting some errors and I am not sure what's causing it. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try this? You should change the database name in the query.

```
DECLARE CURS CURSOR FOR
Select C.CustomerID from Customers C join Orders O on C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID GROUP BY C.CustomerID

DECLARE @CustomerID INT
DECLARE @sqltext varchar(4000);

OPEN CURS
FETCH NEXT FROM CURS INTO @CustomerID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN 

SET @sqltext = 'bcp "Select CustomerID, OrderName, OrderQuantity from [DB].[dbo].Customers C join [DB].[dbo].Orders O on C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID WHERE C.CustomerID = ''' 
    + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @CustomerID) 
    + '''" queryout "D:\Test\customer' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @CustomerID) + '.csv" -c -T -x -t,'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @sqltext

FETCH NEXT FROM CURS INTO @CustomerID
END
CLOSE CURS
DEALLOCATE CURS
```

Comment: Thanks Sarslan,

I am getting these as a result:

output usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile [-m maxerrors] [-f formatfile] [-e errfile] [-F firstrow] [-L lastrow] [-b batchsize] [-n native type] [-c character type] [-w wide character type] [-N keep non-text native] [-V file format version] [-q quoted identifier] [-C code page specifier] [-t field terminator] [-r row terminator] [-i inputfile] [-o outfile] [-a packetsize] [-S server name] [-U username] [-P password]  [-x generate xml format file] [-d database name] [-K application intent] [-l login timeout]

Comment: That means there is some issue with the generation of the BCP command line. Can you add `PRINT @sqltext` on the line before `EXEC master....` and show what it prints?

Comment: No errors - and this is the print result -Sorry I changed the select statement a bit- 

bcp "Select p.policyid, P.brooklandsreference , c.comments , c.dateadded from brooklands.dbo.policydetails P join brooklands.dbo.comments C on P.PolicyID = C.policyID  
where p.policyid = '7279'" queryout "D:\Test\customer7279.csv" -c -T -x

Comment: It seems correct, Which sql server version do you use? I tried it with sql2012.

Comment: @sarslan I am using SQL Server 2014  and Management Studio 2016

Comment: I figured it out - the bcp command MUST be in a single line - Thank you super much

Comment: @sarslan One last question please - the csv file doesn't look well formatted as it should be - is there any settings I can change to sort it?

Comment: Could you give me sample lines for expected and actual result.

Comment: When I open the csv file via excel it's showing the entire SQL row in 1 cell instead of splitting it into columns.

Comment: could you add " -t, " switch after " -x "

Comment: Just FYI: the 'single column' thing you are seeing is purely an artifact of Excel. There's nothing wrong with the file, it's just the way excel opens it. If you open it in notepad you'll see what I mean.